# Global exception handling, should not navigate away. Display error on the page

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, exception

I have implemented Global Exception handling in jsf 2.0 following the code example here:
http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/259014/How-to-add-exception-handling-to-JSF-applications
I do not want the user to be navigated to the error page. I want the user to be on the same page and display a message.
So the code now looks like this:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper
{
    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

    public CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped){
        this.wrapped = wrapped;

    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped(){
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException{
        Iterator iterator = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = (ExceptionQueuedEvent)iterator.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext)event.getSource();
            Throwable throwable = context.getException();
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            final ExternalContext externalContext = fc.getExternalContext();
            final Map<String, Object> requestMap = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
            final ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            //here you do what ever you want with exception
            try {
            fc.getExternalContext().setResponseStatus(500);
            fc.addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "There is an error.", ""));
            }
            finally {
                //remove it from queue
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        getWrapped().handle();
    }
}
```

But with this code, neither the page is not navigated nor the message is displayed. 
If I remove this line of code:

```
fc.getExternalContext().setResponseStatus(500);
```

Then the user is taken to the next page and the message is displayed on that page.

Any idea how I can show the error message on the same page and not navigate the user away ?

Thanks